# How can we compare multiple text in cypress (not wanted and wanted or)

Tags: cypress, or-operator

If I have an element having text 'xyzzy', but I wanted to check this against all these: 'par' or 'xyzzy' or 'arc', how we can do it?

I'm not able to get it with this:

```js
.should('have.text','Ab demo 1').and('have.text','ab demo 2')
```

Can we replace 'and' with 'or'?

Answer (score 7):

Can use satisfy assertion,

```js
cy.get('(//div[@class="xyz"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('satisfy', (text) => text === 'par' || text === 'xyz' || text === 'arc')
```

Answer (score 3):

Can be done in a `.should()` command with a callback function

```js
const texts = ['par', 'xyzzy', 'arc']

cy.get('(//div[@class="xyz"]').eq(2)
  .should($el => {
    const text = $el.text()
    expect(texts.includes(text)).to.eq(true)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

The `oneOf` assertion can go inside `.should()`

```js
cy.get('(//div[@class="xyz"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('be.oneOf', ['par', 'xyzzy', 'arc'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the word `any` and provide the list to match

```js
cy.get('(//div[@class="xyz"]')
  .should('have.any.text', ('Ab demo 1', 'Ab demo 2'))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to use the [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) with [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo selector

```js
cy.get(':contains("xyzzy"), :contains("par"), :contains("arc")')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cypress assertion `to.be.oneOf` and do that. Something like:

```js
cy.get('selector').then(($ele) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim()).to.be.oneOf(['xyzzy', 'par', 'arc'])
})
```

Comment: `to.be.oneOf` is a chai assertion, not a cypress assertion.

Comment: By `cypress assertion` I meant the assertions mentioned in the webpage https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai. But yes `to.be.oneOf` is indeed a chai assertion.