# Check if URL contains this OR this in Cypress

Tags: angular, testing, cucumber, cypress, e2e-testing

In Cypress 10, how can I check that a URL contains something, or something, or something? I know how to check a URL for one thing:

```js
cy.url().should('contains', '/inventory.html');
```

But how do I modify this to check if the url contains /inventory.html OR /cheese.html OR /sunshine.html, without using a bunch of if else statements?

Answer (score 4):

Use `contain.oneOf` like this:

```js
cy.url().should('contain.oneOf', ['/inventory.html', '/cheese.html'])
```

If you generally want to find an assertion syntax look here, e.g [oneOf](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof).

Cypress gives you shortcut of the same syntax with `.should()` but more important, it will retry the assertion.

If you use `.then()` there is no retry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  expect(url).to.contain.oneOf(['/inventory.html', '/something.html'])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the other answers worked then, but they don't for Cypress v12+. The solution is:

```js
cy.url().should('satisfy', (url) => url.includes('/inventory.html') || url.includes('/something.html'));
```

Basically, just use regular JS `includes` after the URL is returned. I saw this answer on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891518).